# How to Use IEnumerator Correctly when button calls multiple functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I am making a card game in which I am trying to make a (0.5f) delay before each card is instantiated. I have my code which instantiates and object

```
public IEnumerator Name(int x,int y, int z)
{

}
```

In the IEnum i have a `yeild return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f)`before all the code with the instantiation.

I call my IEnumerator in 2 different classes 2 times in each by using

```
StartCoroutine(Name(...par...));
```

And on my play game button i have 4 events which use the enum to spawn the cards but there is no delay .

Is there a way to make the cards appear 1 by one .

Thanks for any support.

Comment: You probably should consider using `async/await` than Unity co-routines now that Unity supports `Task`s.   The former is the standard across .NET development whilst co-routines, a legacy Unity invention, are a misuse of `yield/return`.

Comment: @MickyD O I will try that too .Thank you

Comment: How long is an "f"? What's a (0.5f) delay?

Comment: 0.5 seconds . I have tried with just 1 or 2 also doesnt make a difference. I will test the new way and see .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Whatever it is that is currently calling StartCoroutine needs to be the coroutine.

Right now you have code that looks/behaves like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Name(...par...));
StartCoroutine(Name(...par...));
StartCoroutine(Name(...par...));
StartCoroutine(Name(...par...));
```

And all of them are spawning a card and not waiting for each other. You don't want this, so you're going to need to make a fundamental change in how your calls are made so that you can get this behavior:

```
StartCoroutine(SomeMethod(...));

IEnumerator SomeMethod(...) {
    yield return Name(...par...)
    yield return Name(...par...)
    yield return Name(...par...)
    yield return Name(...par...)
}
```