# Am I understanding Coroutines correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing my first Unity game. I have a series of nested functions, let's call them Function1, Function2, etc. Let's say that in Function3, I want to display something for a short time **before any more code gets executed**.

If I make Function3 a Coroutine and exit with a yield return new WaitForSeconds, that does not stop all the code in my other functions from executing, but simply prevents the execution of the rest of the code in Function3, right? Meanwhile, Functions1 & 2 continue on their merry way.

Is there any way of getting what I want without restructuring every function to be coroutines and putting in a boatload of yields and while true statements? (In my actual game, there are quite a few functions ahead of the one I want to be the coroutine.)

I'll add some pseudo-code to illustrate my situation.

Thanks.

```
public Function1()
    {
        .
        .
        Does some stuff
        .
        .
        call Function2()
        .
        .
        Do some more stuff
        .
        .
    }
```

---

```
 public Function2()
 {
    .
    .
    Does some stuff
    .
    .
    StartCoroutine(Function3())
    .
    .
    Does some more stuff
    .
    .
    return to Function2;
 }
```

---

```
IEnumerator Function3()
{
    .
    .
    Does some stuff...
    Now I want to wait for specified time (say, .5 seconds) to display a message, play a sound, etc., **without continuing the code in Function2 or Function1 * *!
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f)
    Then do some more stuff
    .
    .
    return to Function2;
 }
```

Comment: Write code in code blocks on this site, highlight the code and press the button that looks like `{ }`

Comment: `StartCoroutine` does not pause the execution of the function it is in. If you want to wait for a coroutine to finish, then that code needs to go *inside* the coroutine function (or the method itself needs to be a coroutine). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194689/1663383), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085035/1663383), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436595/1663383).

Comment: Thanks. One of Draco18s links sent me to a link for nested coroutines, which helped greatly. I needed to call the last routines with "yield return StartCoroutine()". That suspends execution until my timer routine finished and scroll had finished.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing so, however I prefer to use callback actions which are invoked upon 'completion' of the coroutine.

```
public IEnumerator Function1(Action callback)
{
    // do some stuff
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    // do some stuff
    callback.Invoke();
}

public IEnumerator Function2(Action callback)
{
    // do some stuff
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    // do some stuff
    callback.Invoke();
}

public void CallingMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(Function1(() => 
    {
        StartCoroutine(Function2(() =>
        {
            // whatever other code you want executed
        }));
    }));
}
```

This approach avoids the use of class flags (booleans) which can easily clutter your code. Furthermore it allows for easy reusability of your methods.

Comment: First, thanks to Scott Chamberlain for helping me understand how to format code blocks. I edited my question accordingly (I think).

Immorality: I don't think this does the same thing. I don't want delays in the "upper" functions, only in the last one. I want to suspend execution of the code in the upper functions until the delay in Function3 has expired. Keeping in mind Function2 or 3 might reside in different scripts from Function1.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this by putting something in Update()? For example, if I have a flag that indicates when the delay is complete. Like a loop that would in essence suspend execution of the code in all routines (but still checking the yield statement in Function3) until the flag toggled true. But I'm guessing that wouldn't work, because Update doesn't get executed until the end of the "frame" (whatever that is). I can't believe a simple little delay is this hard to encode.

Comment: `yield Function2()` makes more sense than using callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have both your Function1 and Function2 return `IEnumerator` and then yield to the functions they call:

```
IEnumerator public Function1()
{
    ...
    yield return Function2();
    ...
}
IEnumerator public Function2()
{
    ...
    yield return Function3();
    ...
}
IEnumerator public Function3()
{
    ...
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f); // Or whatever
    ...
}
```

And now call `StartCoroutine(Function1())` instead of just `Function1()`, when invoking it.